# Trying to query data using xpath

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I am a total rookie and am trying to query data from a website and import it to Google docs spreadsheet. I have used firebug/firepath to find the xpath, when i paste the xpath into a cell =importxml(Url, query) it errors. 
Here it is the url: http://www.sportfishingreport.com/pages/boatdetail.php?boat_id=781

```
Boat        Trip Type     Anglers                    Catch
03-22-2015  Full Day    21    48 Ocean Whitefish, 210 Rockfish, 21 Lingcod
```

Can someone help me write the xpath because the xpath that firepath tells me to write errors in google docs.

Thanks in advance, Jess

Comment: Show the code of what you tried so far.

Comment: Tell us the exact error message, show the formula you entered in that cell, the exact XPath expression - and show very clearly what you want the result to be.

Comment: url is: http://www.channelislandssportfishing.com/fish-counts. Each cell has a different xpath to query it. So lets say I want to import the boat name first which is the Erna B. Firepath says the xpath is: html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1].

Comment: I type =importxml(url, "//*html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]") and it comes back error imported xml content cannot be parsed. I would like to query and import the boat name, trip type, number of anglers, and catch, each with a different xpath and am unable to do this. Xpath validates it to a matching node.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tables in the source HTML of the second page you have indicated (that is, http://www.channelislandssportfishing.com/fish-counts). If anything, those tables are generated by Javascript, but then this content cannot be found by `IMPORTXML`, because it operates on the raw source HTML.

But what you get from Firepath is endlessly complicated anyway, because the tool tends to return path expressions that rely on *positions* of nodes, rather than actual values, or IDs, or names. If you look at the source HTML, the portion of HTML that contains "Erna B" looks like

```
<a href="/erna-b-sportfishing" ><span style="color: #000000;">Erna B</a>
```

And there is in fact a trivial XPath expression that selects this content, because the `href` attribute value is unique. To have "Erna B" appear in a cell in Google Sheets, use

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.channelislandssportfishing.com/fish-counts","//a[@href='/erna-b-sportfishing']")
```

For all other cells, look for similar properties that uniquely identify nodes, and turn those into path expressions.

Comment: Hello Mathias Muller, thank you for the answer. I will try it and see if I can figure out what the xpath for the specific nodes are to access the anglers  trip type, and catch data for each cell. I really appreciate your help. I will use your anchor hyper reference method. If i have difficulty i might need to bug you again. Thanks again, Jess

Comment: @jessj You are welcome. Please do not forget to [**accept this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem. Thanks! If you encounter further problems, I think it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: Hello Mathias Muller, I want to import the whole table of data meaning the boat name, trip type and catch data for each cell everyday. Sometimes there are 3 boats and sometimes there are up to 9 boats. How would i do this is there an anchor tag with using the @href that you see that can do this. Thank you, jess

Comment: @jessj As I said, there is no table in the source HTML of that page - it is later generated from Javascript - IMPORTXML cannot find such content. Apart from boat names, it seems all content is dynamically generated.